# Speech recognition is not available in this device

Tags: javascript, cordova, ionic3, cordova-plugins, speech-recognition

From one week I am trying to resolve this error but no luck.

As per my understanding, this plugin uses network call and we are using VPN, so I think VPN could be blocking that network calls. Can we know which network call using this plugin so that I can try to remove that URL,s from blocking list? Then may my issue can be resolved.

The configuration which I am using,

Ionic:

ionic (Ionic CLI) : 4.6.0 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic)
Ionic Framework : ionic-angular 3.9.2
@ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.1

Cordova:

cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.1.2 (cordova-lib@8.1.1)
Cordova Platforms : android 7.1.4
Cordova Plugins : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.3, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 2.3.1, (and 5 other plugins)

System:

Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1 (/Users/-----/Library/Android/sdk)
NodeJS : v10.15.0 (/usr/local/bin/node)
npm : 6.5.0
OS : macOS High Sierra

Comment: Has anyone faced this kind of issue...?

Answer (score 0):

Platform?

Try without VPN to make sure it isn't being blocked.

Have you checked if you meet the platform requirements, as listed https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-speechrecognition